# Output inserted.id giving error must declare table type

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have sql statements as below:

```
Declare @Inserted_FileID as int        

insert into EH_PP_TeacherEvalArtifacts (EH_PP_TEA_OriginalUploadDateTime,EH_PP_TEA_LastModidiedDateTime,EH_PP_TEA_FileVersionNum,EH_PP_TEA_FileName,EH_PP_TEA_FileDesc,EH_PP_TE_TeacherEvalID,EH_PP_TEA_UploadedBy)        
    OUTPUT INSERTED.EH_PP_TEA_FileID  into @Inserted_FileID
    values(getdate(),getdate(),@EH_PP_TEA_FileVersionNum,@EH_PP_TEA_FileName,@EH_PP_TEA_FileDesc,@EH_PP_TE_TeacherEvalID,@EH_PP_TEA_UploadedByAccountID)
```

on :

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.EH_PP_TEA_FileID  into @Inserted_FileID
```

Its showing me error that:

must declare table variable `@Inserted_FileID`

I just want to store currently inserted fileid into `@Inserted_FileID` integer variable.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF `@Inserted_FileID` is identity column then USE

`**SET Inserted_FileID = @@identity**`

IF not then use Following :

```
Declare @Inserted_FileID as int
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1),FILE_ID VARCHAR(4))

insert into EH_PP_TeacherEvalArtifacts 
(EH_PP_TEA_OriginalUploadDateTime,
 EH_PP_TEA_LastModidiedDateTime,
 EH_PP_TEA_FileVersionNum,
 EH_PP_TEA_FileName,
 EH_PP_TEA_FileDesc,
 EH_PP_TE_TeacherEvalID,
 EH_PP_TEA_UploadedBy) 
values
(getdate(),
 getdate(),
 @EH_PP_TEA_FileVersionNum,
 @EH_PP_TEA_FileName,
 @EH_PP_TEA_FileDesc,
 @EH_PP_TE_TeacherEvalID,
 @EH_PP_TEA_UploadedByAccountID)   

INSERT INTO @TempTable 
Select top 1  EH_PP_TEA_FileID 
from EH_PP_TeacherEvalArtifacts 
order by EH_PP_TEA_LastModidiedDateTime DESC

Select @Inserted_FileID = FILE_ID  from @TempTable
```